# gitlab can't deliver email normally

Tags: gitlab

I have installed the gitlab-omnibus version in my centos.It seems that everything is OK.But when a newer want to sign up, he/she must recieve the comfirm enalbe which send from gitlab.I have config the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb according to the gitlab's office document.
And I check my `var/log/email`,I found the message is as follow:

```
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/cleanup[5899]: 9789EC3907: message-id=<201504220705.t3M75dkU005893@iZ23syflhhzZ>
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ sendmail[5893]: t3M75dkU005893: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32576, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 9789EC3907)
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/qmgr[5724]: 9789EC3907: from=<>, size=4301, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/smtpd[5896]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/cleanup[5899]: A6D63C38FD: message-id=<201504220705.t3M75dkU005893@iZ23syflhhzZ>
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/qmgr[5724]: A6D63C38FD: from=<>, size=4456, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/local[5900]: 9789EC3907: to=<postmaster@iZ23syflhhzZ.localdomain>, orig_to=<postmaster@iZ23syflhhzZ>, relay=local, delay=0.1, delays=0.05/0.04/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as A6D63C38FD)
Apr 22 15:05:39 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/qmgr[5724]: 9789EC3907: removed
Apr 22 15:05:40 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/smtp[5902]: A6D63C38FD: to=<hiufan@qq.com>, orig_to=<postmaster@iZ23syflhhzZ>, relay=mx3.qq.com[113.108.16.62]:25, delay=0.73, delays=0.01/0.03/0.12/0.57, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx3.qq.com[113.108.16.62] said: 550 Mail content denied. http://service.mail.qq.com/cgi-bin/help?subtype=1&&id=20022&&no=1000726 (in reply to end of DATA command))
Apr 22 15:05:40 iZ23syflhhzZ postfix/qmgr[5724]: A6D63C38FD: removed
```

It is very confused that I am not setting the email called `hiufan@qq.com`,I just setting the `066337@sina.com` as the default sender email.
Here is my setting of `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.sina.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 25
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "066337@sina.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "xxxxxx"
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "sina.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false

gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "066337@sina.com"
user["git_user_email"] = "066337@sina.com"
```

Could anyone tell me why this happened?Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the second last line of the log file

```
to=<hiufan@qq.com>, orig_to=<postmaster@iZ23syflhhzZ>, relay=mx3.qq.com[113.108.16.62]:25, delay=0.73, delays=0.01/0.03/0.12/0.57, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx3.qq.com[113.108.16.62] said: 550 Mail content denied.   (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

If `hiufan@qq.com` is the email address of the user registering, that
indicates that the message was sent by the gitlab machine but rejected by the receiving mail server (at `qq.com`):

```
status=bounced (host mx3.qq.com[113.108.16.62] said: 550 Mail content denied
```

Looking at the given link (using google translate) 
http://service.mail.qq.com/cgi-bin/help?subtype=1&&id=20022&&no=1000726
it seems that it was rejected as it is identified as spam/bulk email. (I guess that if you do read chinese the error message makes more sense)

If so, I don't think there is much you can do at the gitlab side. You can perhaps try to edit the confirmation message template, but it *is* and automatically generated email and there is always a risk of a spam filter identifying it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab confirmation emails can easily be identified as spam. And QQMail is really powerful in identifying and rejecting spam.

My suggestion would be changing the config of Gitlab, to stop needing confirmation email for registration.

Comment: It is also a good idea.But how to disabled the confirmation?Which config file do I need to modifie?